# The set of $k$-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, union of countably many countable set is countable, does this violate Cantor's Theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

If $\mathcal{P}_k$, the set $k-$element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable (meaning subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ containing $k$ elements) for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. **(I'm pretty sure that this is correct.)**

And the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) = \cup_{k=0}^{+\infty} 
 \mathcal{P}_k$ **(I might be wrong here)**, is a union of countably many countable sets, then shouldn't $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be countable?

This contradicts Cantor's Theorem.

I know that my reasoning is flawed, but I can't seem to see where.

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\not=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{P}_k$ - think about, for example, the set of **even numbers**.

Comment: The set of the finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is countable because we can easily enumerate them (for $k=1,2,3,\cdots$ list all subsets of $\mathbb N$ having no entry beyond $k$). For the infinite subsets this is no more possible since they correpond $1-1$ with the infinite binary strings , and the Cantor method shows easily that they are uncountable.

Comment: Just to emphasize what was implicit in the earlier comments: $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty\mathcal P_k$ is not $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ but omly the set of **finite** subsets of $\mathbb N$.